# How to query based on a list of a custom object using two of its properties

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework

My problem is:

```
using( var ctxA = new AEntities())
using( var ctxB = new BEntities())
{

     List<A> listOfA = from A in ctxA.A select new { Boo = A.Boo, Foo = A.Foo};

     //do some operation to detach listOfA

     //The code bellow does not work!
     List<B> listOfB = from B in ctxB.B
                           join A in listOfA on 
                             new { B.Boo, B.Foo} equals new {A.Boo, A.Foo} 
                           select B;
}
```

How can  I make such query, not getting the exceptions bellow?

> Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Or

> System.NotSupportedException: The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts.

**EDIT**

Based on your answer Anshish I changed my query select code to (and it worked):

```
List<B> listOfB = new List<B>();
listOfA.foreach( A =>{

     lisfOfB.add( ctxB.B.Where( B=> B.Foo.Equals(A.Foo)).Where( B=> B.Boo.Equals(A.Boo));

});
```

But the problem now is that I'm doing listOfA.Count queries to the dabase, I'm not?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you cannot compare user defined types. i.e. you cannot compare object of classes.

Try using some internal primitive property of object to compare. Example:

For Example this is my model.

```
public class Student
{
public int StudentId {get; set;}
public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

And If i have two objects:

```
Student s1= new Student{ StudentId=1, Name="Stu1"};
Student s2= new Student{ StudentId=2, Name="Stu2"};
```

And If i need to compare them:
then

```
if( s1.StudentId==s2.StudentId)
```

or

```
if(s1.Name==s2.Name)
```

This should work. Simply writing

```
if(s1==s2)
```

will not work as s1 and s2 are not primitive type and the runtime doesn't know how to compare two non primitive type objects.

Comment: Any suggestion to refactor my code to get the listOfB based on listOfA?

Comment: Please check the edit. Also, I think you need to replace the clause after on keyword to match to some primitive type.

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to do a simple join because EF needs to be able to turn the expression into a server-side expression, which isn't going to work mixing in client-side objects. I think you're going to have to do something like the following:

```
using( var ctxA = new AEntities())
using( var ctxB = new BEntities())
{
    List<A> listOfA = from A in ctxA.A select new { Boo = A.Boo, Foo = A.Foo};

    var boos = listOfA.Select( a => a.Boo );
    var foos = listOfA.Select( a => a.Foo );

    var listOfB = ctxB.B.Where( b => boos.Contains( b.Boo ) && foos.Contains( b.Foo ) ).ToList();
}
```

Comment: The problem with your answer is that if I have A{ Boo=1, Foo=2} and A{ Boo=2, Foo=1} the B{ Boo=1, Foo=1} and B{ Boo=2, Foo=2} will be returned and that's cannot be.